# How can I get USMT with server to run through Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell, usmt

I've been trying to get scanstate and loadstate to backup to a server but everytime I try it returns **error code 27: Invalid store path; check the store parameter and/or file system permissions.** I have shared the folder out to allow everyone and domain computers full control. I can run the scanstate/loadstate with the exact same parameters on the local machine.

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $sourceComputer -ScriptBlock{C:\USMTFiles\scanstate.exe \\server\migstore /i:c:\usmtfiles\MigUser.xml}`

Comment: The user you use for Invoke-Command has permissions to `\\Server\migstore`. If you manually test that ScriptBock on $SourceComputer does it work then? Did you try adding credentials "`-Credential (Get-Credential)`" that both have permissions for remoting and accessing \\server\migstore? Can you try `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {cmd /c "C:\USMTFiles\scanstate.exe \\server\migstore /i:c:\usmtfiles\MigUser.xml"}`

Comment: Yes the script is run on an admin account with access to the share, I can run it with the same account locally and I have also tried to add -Credential I will try your suggestion when I get back to the office

Comment: Still getting error 27 when trying to invoke cmd